# WinApi Application build from Visual studio 6 cannot run on Window Server 2012

Tags: visual-studio, window, windows-server-2012

My WinApi application build from Visual studio 6 can be run normally on MS Windows 7,8 and 10.

But it cannot be launch on one of Window Server 2012 machine with error message :

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0x0000142). Click OK to close the application.
```

On same machine, when i run my application built from Visual studio 2013, it can run normally.

Is there any settings that require to set during build from VS 6 to work? Or is there any extra installation package on server machine that can help me solve this problem?

**Note 1 :** The application VS2013 built is in test phase and is to avoid using on production environment at this stage.

**Note 2 :** The application built from VS6 can run on other Server 2012 machine. Problem occurred on one specific machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surely it actually says 0xC0000142?  You'll have to find out what DLL is unhappy.

Comment: @HansPassant : I try Dependency walker. things seems fine